# How to solve this second-order linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone have any tips on how to get going on this equation?

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+y=\sin(t)\cdot e^t$

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic equation  is 
$$r^2+1=0$$
and their roots are $r=\pm i$ then the solutions of the homogeneous equation  are
$$y_h= a\cos t+b\sin t,\qquad a,b\in \Bbb R$$
Now  since $\sin t=\rm{Im}(e^{it})$ we look for a particular solution on the form
$$y_p(x)=\alpha e^{(i+1)t}$$
so substituting this equation in the ODE gives
$$\alpha=\frac1{2i+1}=\frac15(1-2i)$$
so taking the imaginary part we find 
$$y_p(t)=e^t\left(\frac15\sin t-\frac25\cos t\right)$$
and finaly the solutions are
$$y(t)=y_h(t)+y_p(t)$$

Comment: Very nice, my friend!